# Why can't I declare an external variable in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, external, block, declare

I need to declare a variable inside an `if` statement. Then I will use it on the outside. But as far as I know, there are no external variables in C#. But I need to do this.

I have two classes both derived from one class.

Base class: `Operand`
Derived classes: `NormalOperand` `SpecialOperand`

```
bool normal
```

Declared somewhere

```
if(normal)
    NormalOperand o = stack.Pop() as NormalOperand;
else
    SpecialOperand o = stack.Pop() as SpecialOperand;
```

I don't want to deal this differences below. Is there any hack to do that? Or do I have to deal with it everywhere I do something related to this?

Comment: Very hard to understand.  Surely you need a virtual method.

Comment: thanks, you inspired me. I think i can change my code, so i won't need this 'if'.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make it more clear, but my keyboard layout didn't let me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see the issue, just declare `o` as the base class `Operand`.

```
Operand o = stack.Pop(); // add as Operand if needed
```

Later if you need to know the type of `o` (using virtual/abstract methods on base class should avoid this) then use:

```
if (o is NormalOperand)
{
    // TODO: maybe check for null
    (o as NormalOperand).NormalSpecificMethod();
}
```

Comment: +1.  I suggested using `typeof()`, your answer is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the only reason you want to declare such a varaible as external is because you want to call different methods on them.

For example:

```
 normal = true;

 ...

 o.DoSomethingNormal()

 normal = false;
 o.DoSomethingSpecial();
```

If you have a look at this code, and realize that C# is a statically typed language you will understand that this can never compile.

But if you want to call a method that is declared on both Normal and Special you could should declare this method in an Interface or base class and cast the stack.Pop() to that type. That way you will use polyformism and it will work.

In your case:

```
Operand o = stack.Pop() as Operand;
o.DoSomething();
```

Comment: So this means i can't do this in C#. Thanks, i need to change my design.

Comment: The problem is even if you could declare your variable as external then you would still have to choose if you would call DoSomethingNormal() or DoSomethingSpecial() so it wouldn't give you any more value

Comment: No, i will use operator overloading. If i could put the object in the right reference, there will be no problem. I will post this again in the future with better explanation to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should be declaring the variable before the if statement, declaring it as an `Operand`. In this situation, you don't need an if statement at all, nor do you need the `boolean normal`. Just declare it as an `Operand` and use polymorphism to do whatever else it is you need to do.

```
Operand o = stack.Pop() as Operand;
```

As you say, you don't want to deal with the differences below, you shouldn't need to know whether o is special or not. Or do you?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
bool normal = ...

Operand o = null;
if (normal) o = stack.Pop() as NormalOperand; Enter code here`else o = stack.Pop() as SpecialOperand;
```

I am not sure I understand it though. I mean, this makes sense only if you need to do other stuff within the `if`-statement. otherwise, as George suggests, you can always do `o = stack.Pop()` and then check type using as and null checking.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, your example doesn't make any sense as both those temporaries disappear anyway.  But let's ignore that little bit.

Given that these operands are on the same stack, we can assume they are both derived from a common class.  I'll assume that is `Operand`.

```
Operand o = Stack.Pop();
```

Now, I also assume you want to *do* something with this code.  What is it?  Why do you have to know?  If you really just want to know what *type* it is, you can say:

```
if(o.GetType() == typeof(NormalOperand))
{
}
else if(o.GetType() == typeof(SpecialOpernad))
{
}
```